# write datagridview data in to xml file

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

I am new to c#, this may be very easy question.

In my application there is a `Form` in which I have datagridview `dgvBill` and a Button `btnClick`. I declared columns to it by clicking the extender and selecting `add columns`. After executing the form, I written some text to each column in `dgvBill`. When I click on `btnClick` it is creating an xml file but with no data in it. (why the data is not being added ?)

The created XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet />
```

I have tried the below code:

**btnClick Event**

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.WriteXml(@"..\..\Customer_Info\" + lblCustId.Text + ".xml");
dgvBill.DataSource = ds;  /* also tried ds.Tables[0] */
```

`lblCustId` is a label in the `Form`

*Optional*: can I make each cell of datagridview into ComboBox?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem solved when I created a new empty xml file (which has only created column names)
and read the xml file in a dataset object (on form load event).  I used the same dataset object to write on different xml file (on button click event). I am sure that this is not the correct way but it worked. Please post here if you have any other good suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

use `dataGridView1.EndEdit();` and then create the `XML`

Comment: Thankyou for your response. I tried it but its not working(showing the same empty xml file). [I have written like this](http://ideone.com/tgFIw)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are writing XML before assigning the dataset to dgvBill. Try putting after.

Answer (score 0):

First create binding source and load data from binding source to datatable and create a new dataset and add datatable to dataset and then write to XML file from dataset.

```
BindingSource bs = (BindingSource )MyGridView.DataSource;
DataTable dt= (DataTable ) bs.DataSource;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
ds.Tables[0].WriteXml("E:\\test2.xml");
```

Comment: It is showing Error - "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." **Error Point:** `DataTable dt = (DataTable)bs.DataSource;` . BTW thanks for response.

Comment: I think your dataGrid is empty..check it.

Comment: yes it is empty when it is loaded. After Executing my application, i am writing some text in it. which is not adding to XML file. please help.

Comment: have u put that line in your code  dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;

Comment: yes,  I have created this datasource in buttonclick event while the empty datagridview on form load event. [here is my code](http://ideone.com/hYocE).

Comment: I used it. still same problem.

Comment: [Please check my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12743993/1577396) is there any other way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

COuld you check that you have set the datapropertyname for your columns,
Here is my code. This works fine
form3.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
 namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
 {
  public partial class Form32 : Form
    {
    public Form32()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("row");
        dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("UserName", typeof(string));
        dt.Rows.Add(1, "Tamer");
        dt.Rows.Add(2, "Foo");
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "row";
    }

    private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = @"C:\users\tamer\desktop\data.xml";
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(fileName);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
            dataGridView1.DataMember = "row";
        }
    }

    private void Form3_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = @"C:\users\tamer\desktop\data.xml";
        DataSet dataSet = (DataSet)dataGridView1.DataSource;
        dataSet.WriteXml(fileName);

    }
}
```

}

form3.designer.cs

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    partial class Form32
    {
        /// 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// 
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.Id = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.UserName = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // dataGridView1
        // 
        this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
        this.Id,
        this.UserName});
        this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
        this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(582, 337);
        this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(246, 377);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.button1.Text = "button1";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        // 
        // Id
        // 
        this.Id.DataPropertyName = "Id";
        this.Id.HeaderText = "Id";
        this.Id.Name = "Id";
        // 
        // UserName
        // 
        this.UserName.DataPropertyName = "UserName";
        this.UserName.HeaderText = "UserName";
        this.UserName.Name = "UserName";
        // 
        // Form32
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(632, 431);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
        this.Name = "Form32";
        this.Text = "Form3";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form3_Load);
        this.FormClosed += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventHandler(this.Form3_FormClosed);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Id;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn UserName;
}
```

}